# Is it possible to build a semantically unambigous grammar / language / graph?

Tags: compiler, language-design, optimization

It's been a long time that I had an idea of a semantic constraint as compiler optimizations which allows for sophisticated high level optimization allowing you to transform the AST/CFG based on a SFG (semantic flow graph).

To give you a simple example I'll simplify the code of a reddit question which asked about two versions of a semantically equal code:

```typescript
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
const res = arr.filter(e => e%2 === 0).map(e => e * 2);
```

```typescript
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
const res = arr.reduce((res, e) => {
    if (e % 2 === 0) res.push(e * 2);
    return res;

},[])
```

While the code follows an entirely different logic, the result is the same.

Is it possible to derive a semantically unambigous graph (SFG) from a CFG (enriched with dataflow analysis) which would be the same for both versions of the code?

Could you write a code generator which generates logically optimized CFGs from an SFG?

Is this somehow possible? Could we use sophisticated LLMs to reason about semantics or would there be a mathematical way of solving this logically?

Comment: see [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: Fairly sure the answer is "no" for Turing completeness reasons for all but very small languages.

Comment: It is not merely semantics. Your question in fact requires the ability to algorithmically, or to have an LLM correctly postulate whether two mathematical statements (not merely a computable function) are equivalent for every element in a particular given set of discourse. Certainly doable for simple cases (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superoptimization ), but not doable for every conceivable case. See also, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296868/when-two-theorems-are-equivalent-formal-definition

Comment: I think you're looking for the concept of a "strongly normalizing" term rewriting system (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_form_(abstract_rewriting)). Later in that article, you'll notice that the Lambda Calculus (equivalent to Turing Completeness) is not normalizing. But you can design a language/system that is both strongly normalizing and somewhat useful. You'd lack some features though, like unbounded loops or unbounded recursion. LLMs can't help. They're not magic, they just produce a plausible-looking token stream. But here, you're dealing with things that are *provably impossible*

Comment: Thanks for the educated opinions! I'll try to understand this better and update my question to be more useful. I will need a while to read through the links you all provided. I also think it might be provably impossible, but I'm not a mathematician.